# Find third vector with opposite deviation

Tags: geometry, vectors, 3d

Say there are two unit vectors a and b. I want to find unit vector c such that the deviation between c and a is the opposite to the deviation between a and b. The angles between c and a, and a and b will be will be the same but in opposite directions and all three vectors will fit on a plane. How can I find c?

Comment: What do you know about the vector you're looking for and what have you tried in order to find it?

Comment: I think I've stated in the question everything I know about it. I tried looking at the change in azimuth and dip between a and b and creating a vector with azimuth and dip of a minus that dip, but it got messy and didn't work, must a better way.

Comment: Ok I've sketched the idea. Usually when dealing with vectors you want to work in a setting without 'implementation details', such as the coordinate system (like you tried with polar coordinates). So as far as possible we stick to geometrical methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We want to find $c$ such that $a$ is exactly in-between $b,c$. To do so, we need to reflect $b$ about $a$. The easiest way is to project $b$ onto $a$, which is $(b \cdot a)a$ since $a$ is a unit vector. And then you just need to reverse the component $b - (b \cdot a)a$. So you get $(b \cdot a)a - (b - (b \cdot a)a) = 2 (b\cdot a)a - b$, which should make sense because it's exactly like reflecting in a mirror (2 times mirror position minus original position).

Comment: I would guess it could be found by adding the two and then normalising the result? By drawing a picture I don't think this is the result I want though, this will create a unit vector in between a and b, rather than one on the side of a opposite to the side that b is on

Comment: @ayeayeron: Please see my edited answer, which should now address the correct question.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's really understandable.

Comment: @ayeayeron: You're welcome!

Comment: A note in case anyone comes across this: the projection of b onto a should be dot(b, a) * b.

Comment: @ayeayeron: Lol! Sorry about that careless mistake. I'll fix it now! And it's $(b \cdot a)a$ (project onto $a$), not $(b \cdot a)b$. =)